# How to create generic method in javascript to build json request according to inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have method that create Json request according to 3 input arguments:

```
function jsonRequest(_action, _data1, _data2){
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
        data:{
            action: _action
           ,data1: _data1
           ,data2: _data2   
        }
    });
 return jsonData;
}
```

What if I want to input unknown count of parameters, lets say 4.

So how my function should be to take care about?

Something like:

```
jsonRequest("103","blabla","bobob", ....);
```

It must be generic to handle any count of parameters.

In my example I didn't use angularjs, but you welcome.

Please, help,

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions have a hidden array-like variable called `arguments` which contain everything that was passed into that function during invocation. It would be similar to:

```
function jsonRequest(){
  var _action = arguments[0];
  var _data1 = arguments[1];
  var _data2 = arguments[2];

  //the rest of the code here

}
```

You could loop over the arguments, and append to an object the data you need. You can set the first iteration to append `_action`, and the rest to append `_dataN`, where `N` is the index.

But `arguments` only contain values, no names. I suggest you pass in an object to your function instead.

```
function jsonRequest(data){
  return JSON.stringify({data : data});
}

jsonRequest({
  action : ...,
  data1 : ...,
  data2 : ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I need fetch their names to build request. Please, give me an example. Thanks

Comment: Well, this is what `JSON.stringify` does, convert `{action:..,data:..}` to String. Auto align code in Netbeans expends request to several rows because of object structure. I want to prevent it by creating single method (or service in angularjs)